# Установка ssl сертификата на Nginx

Tags: windows, nginx, ssl

Пробую установить на web-сервер сертификат ssl.
  В настройках Nginx прописываю:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
events {
     worker_connections  1024;
}
 http {
    include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;
gzip  on;

server {
    listen     80;
    server_name  my_site.ru;
    return 301 https://my_site.ru$request_uri;
    location ~ \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|css|js|txt|wsdl)(\?\w+)?$ {
        root C:/vhost/my_site.ru/web;
        index index.php;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
server {
   listen     443;
    ssl on; 
    ssl_certificate      C:/ssl\certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  C:/ssl\secretKey.key;
    server_name my_site.ru;
    access_log logs/nginx_vhost_access.log;
    error_log logs/nginx_vhost_error.log;
    location ~ \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|css|js|txt|wsdl)(\?\w+)?$ {
       root c:/vhost/my_site.ru/web;
        index index.php;
    }   
}
```

}

В результате сертификат начинает работать, но перенаправляет меня по этому домену в каталог C:/nginx/html (собственно, в каталог с nginx).
   Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так в настройках? Какие настройки нужно сделать, чтобы обращаться в нужный каталог?
  P.S. если убрать блок с настройками сертификата и закомментировать перенаправление (обращаемся по http), то при запросе выводится нужный сайт.

У меня получился такой конфиг:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
   http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
     keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
     server {
        listen      80;
        server_name  my_site.ru;
        return 301 https://my_site.ru$request_uri;
        location ~ \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|css|js|txt|wsdl)(\?\w+)?$ {
            root C:/vhost/my_site.ru/web;
            index index.php;
        }

    listen      443;
    ssl on; 
    ssl_certificate      C:/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  C:/ssl/secretKey.key;

    server_name my_site.ru;
    access_log logs/nginx_vhost_access.log;
    error_log logs/nginx_vhost_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

При запросе выводит ошибку SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так с конфигурацией?

Comment: Чуть выше? Полный исходник конфига дайте :)

Comment: Спасибо за замечание :) Готово))

Comment: поменяйте местами блок location / {..}и server{..} для ssl )

Comment: перед `listen      443;` пропущен `server {`

Comment: т.е. должна быть конструкция  server{ listen: 80; server{isten: 433;}} ? Не разрешает так делать((

Comment: @Ann Нет! Не такая!!! А такая server{ listen 80;}..server{listen 443; location /{...}}

Comment: Как пометить ваш комментарий как ответ?

Comment: добавил в ответы

Answer (score 2):

У вас в конфиге не правильно определены и размечены секции.
Для того чтобы nginx начал правильно работать с ssl, вы должны разделить `server` для 80 и 443 порта.
Пример

> server{ listen 80;}..server{listen 443;... location /{...}}

после того как вы исправите свой конфиг, проверить его правильность вы можете командой

> $nginx -t

если не выдаст никаких ошибок, смело стартуйте сам сервер.